# Flutter doesn't compile because lsq_solverno.dart doens't exist

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting an issue trying to compile an application in the flutter dev channel, I have tried with master channel too, but it doesn't work.

I got this issue:

`Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.
The following Dart file:
  C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\gestures.dart
...refers, in an import, to the following library:
  C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\gestures\lsq_solverno.dart
Unfortunately, that library does not appear to exist on your file system.`

I have this YAML file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: ^3.0.4
  http: ^0.11.3+16
  cached_network_image: ^0.4.1
  share: ^0.5.2
  graphql_flutter: ^0.9.4
  camera: ^0.2.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  redux: ^3.0.0
  flutter_redux: ^0.5.2
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^3.0.3392
  vibrate: ^0.0.4
```

I also tried to run the flutter_gallery project from Flutter GitHub examples, it ran the first time, but now, it indicates the same issue that I am getting with my project.

Comment: Try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct file name would be

```
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\gestures\lsq_solver.dart
```

instead of

```
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\gestures\lsq_solverno.dart
```

Your Flutter installation is corrupted. You probably accidentally modified a File in the Flutter install directory.

You can run the following command from the Flutter install directory to check

```
git status
```

To fix run in the Flutter install directory

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Comment: Just to know, why making a stash `save` and then `drop` (that delete the stash), instead of just a simple `checkout` after the `clean`? (I mean, if you want to stash something to preserve it, don't drop it). But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I didn't come up with this myself but from what I remember it's about avoiding messages about changes getting lost.

Comment: Uhm well if you do `git checkout .` on OSX say nothing, but maybe some other GUI tools could. In some scenario this could be true indeed, okay. Thanks.